# How to fix 503 Service Unavailable in Magento 1.x

Tags: magento-1.9

I didn't install any new extension, checked and deleted file maintenance, but it still didn't work, please help me.

Comment: Have you removed **`/var/cache`** folder?

Answer (score 3):

Try seeing if the file **maintenance.flag** exist in your Magento root directory.

If you see this file, remove it and the error will go away.

See below screenshot for it:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

This will help you for your solution.

Find `**cache**` folder in your project and remove that folder and find `**maintenance.flag**` and also remove it from your website root.